# Callback to Observable

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore, rx-java2

I've got this function getting documents from Cloud Firestore:

```
fun getBasicItems(callback: (MutableList<FireStoreBasicItem>) -> Unit) {
    fireStore.collection("BasicItems")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val basicItems = mutableListOf<FireStoreBasicItem>()
                for (document in task.result!!) {
                    val fireStoreBasicItem = document.toObject(FireStoreBasicItem::class.java)
                    basicItems.add(fireStoreBasicItem)
                    callback(basicItems)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

In my `ViewModel` I want to transform this to an `Observable` an then to a `ViewState`:

```
private fun loadDataTransformer(): ObservableTransformer<ItemEvent.LoadDataEvent, ItemsViewState> {
    return ObservableTransformer { event ->
        event.map {
                 itemRepository.getBasicItems(){myBasicItemList -> Observable.just(myBasicItemList)}

    }
}
```

I tried it also with `Observable.fromCallable`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: My Solution**

```
private fun loadDataTransformer(): ObservableTransformer<ItemEvent.LoadDataEvent, ItemsViewState> {
    return ObservableTransformer { event ->
        event.flatMap {
            Single.create<MutableList<FireStoreBasicItem>> {
                itemRepository.getBasicItems { myBasicItemList ->
                    it.onSuccess(myBasicItemList)
                }
            }.toObservable()
                .map {
                    ItemsViewState.ItemDataState(it)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to use `Single` instead of `Observable` if you are expecting only one list of items. Then you can use `Single.create`:

```
private fun loadDataTransformer(): Single<ItemsViewState> =
    Single.create { emitter ->
        itemRepository.getBasicItems() { myBasicItemList ->
            val viewState =  // do some transformations
            emitter.onSuccess(viewState)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to also handle the `if(!task.isSuccessful) {` branch with a `single.onError`.